# Updating our old “translation or proofreading” close reason

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, close-reasons

Thinking about updating our “translation or proofreading” (because it contains the old “*French Language and Usage*” name), we thought of adding some more details about what is necessary to make the question on-topic. This phrasing was suggested by Gilles:

> We are not a text translation or proofreading service. If you're translating into French, be specific about the word or expression you want help with, and explain the meaning and provide context. If you're asking about the correctness of a sentence, tell us which specific word or construction you are unsure about.

For reference here is the old close reason:

> French Language & Usage is not a text translation or proofreading service. Questions about translation from French to another language and translations and proofreading of whole texts are off-topic.

If everyone's happy with this change (post an answer here to suggest improvements), we'll ask Stack Exchange to update the current close reason so that all occurrences of the old site's name are removed.

Comment: Upvoted to show I'd be happy with the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Shog9](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/users/103/shog9) has changed the wording of the close reason.

Thank you.